No more authentication methods available with Apache Mina SSHD
I'm facing an issue while trying to authenticate an SSH session using the Apache Mina SSHD library in Java in a spring boot microservice project. I have a working implementation using JSch that connects successfully with a private key, but the equivalent code in Apache Mina SSHD fails with the error:
org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available                                                                                                             org.apache.sshd.common.future.AbstractSshFuture.verifyResult(AbstractSshFuture.java:141) ~[sshd-common-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]                                                          org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultAuthFuture.verify(DefaultAuthFuture.java:56) ~[sshd-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]                                                                    org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultAuthFuture.verify(DefaultAuthFuture.java:35) ~[sshd-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]                                                                   org.apache.sshd.common.future.VerifiableFuture.verify(VerifiableFuture.java:43) ~[sshd-common-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
Here is the code implementation:
try (SshClient sshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient()) {
    sshClient.start();

    try (ClientSession session =
            sshClient.connect(user, host, port).verify(ftpTimeOutInSeconds * 1000L).getSession()) {
   
            Path privateKeyPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "key.pem");
            FileKeyPairProvider fileKeyPairProvider = new FileKeyPairProvider(privateKeyPath);
            Iterable<KeyPair> keyPairs = fileKeyPairProvider.loadKeys(session);


            if (keyPairs.iterator().hasNext()) {
                session.addPublicKeyIdentity(keyPairs.iterator().next());
            }
        

        session.auth().verify(ftpTimeOutInSeconds * 1000L);
        LOGGER.info("Session authenticated successfully!");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("I/O Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("General Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
}

The error occurs in the code line
session.auth().verify(ftpTimeOutInSeconds * 1000L);
Here is the equivalent JSch Implementation that is working fine:
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session1 = null;

try {
  
    Path privateKeyPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "key.pem");
    jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath.toString());

    session1 = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session1.setTimeout(ftpTimeOutInSeconds * 1000);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session1.setConfig(config);

    session1.connect();
    LOGGER.info("Connected and authenticated successfully!");
} catch (JSchException e) {
    LOGGER.error("JSch Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (session1 != null && session1.isConnected()) {
        session1.disconnect();
    }
}

What could be the reason for the authentication failure in the Apache Mina SSHD implementation, and how can I resolve this issue? Any insights or recommendations for debugging further would be greatly appreciated!
